# yii -> dropDownList -> CHtml::listData -> set selected value

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, selected, yii-chtml

How can I set the selected value in the following statement:

```
echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'land_id',
    CHtml::listData(ListeLand::model()->findAll(), 'iso', 'landname'),
    array('class'=>'span4 chosen','maxlength'=>20)
);
```

I want to set in the list:

```
iso = AT
landname = Österreich
```

as selected value.

EDITED -> The solution:

```
echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'land_id',
    CHtml::listData(ListeLand::model()->findAll(), 'iso', 'landname'),
    array(
                'class'=>'span4 chosen',
                'maxlength'=>20,
                'options' => array('AT'=>array('selected'=>true)),
    )
);
```

Comment: Found the solution: `'options' => array('AT'=>array('selected'=>true)),`

Comment: The other options is to set `$model->land_id = 'AT';`

Comment: @E2B you should enter your solution as an answer, and mark it as the correct one.

Comment: ok, I've already done. But I cannot accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works..

```
echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'land_id',
    CHtml::listData(ListeLand::model()->findAll(), 'iso', 'landname'),
    array(
                'class'=>'span4 chosen',
                'maxlength'=>20,
                'options' => array('AT'=>array('selected'=>true)),
    )
);
```