# Yii 1.1.3 setting selected value of dependent dropdown

Tags: php, yii

I have 3 dependent dropdowns on my page for creation of entity.

```
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('OpenLessons[Building]', '', $buildingList,array(
        'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST', 
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('ajax/floorList'), //url to call.
        'update'=>'#OpenLessons_Floor', //selector to update
        ))); 
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('OpenLessons[Floor]','', array(),array(
        'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST',     
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('ajax/roomList'),
        'update'=>'#OpenLessons_Class_ID',
        )));
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('OpenLessons[Class_ID]',$model->Class_ID, array());
```

Now I want to give them selected options while edit:
I found how to give selected options. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938782/yii-dropdownlist-chtmllistdata-set-selected-value) how to do it.
First select has this code:

```
<select name="OpenLessons[Building]" id="OpenLessons_Building">
<option value="19">primary school</option>
<option value="6">high school</option>
</select>
```

So, I want to set it's value to high school for example.

```
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('OpenLessons[Building]', '', $buildingList,array(
            'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST', 
            'url'=>CController::createUrl('ajax/floorList'), 
            'update'=>'#OpenLessons_Floor', 
            'options' => array('High school'=>array('selected'=>true)),
//Also tried this 'options' => array('6'=>array('selected'=>true)),
            )));
```

And chosen value while editing entity is always - primary school. What's wrong?
**UPDATE**
@Tristup helped me to set value of first dropdown, but there are two more dependent dropdowns and I have problems with it.
Here is my [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884693/yii-1-1-3-setting-selected-value-of-dependent-dropdown-part-2)

Comment: gonna create one more question and post link here. There is more problems there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for the dropDownList is the default selection.

```html
Chtml::dropDownList($name, $select, $data)
```

Example :

```html
$options = array ('0' => 'Select A Value', '1' => 'Tristup','2'=>'Sergey');
echo CHtml::dropDownList('mySelect', '0', $options);
```

here '0' is the value for the default selection.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: got an issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884693/yii-1-1-3-setting-selected-value-of-dependent-dropdown-part-2

Comment: Dependent dropdowns are not selected.